# Theme.AppCompat.Dialog theme creates empty (dead) space

Tags: android, dialog, themes

In my application, I am using an Activity with the theme "Theme.AppCompat.Dialog" to display it as a dialog. That works out well, however, the dialog fills the entire screen height, leaving a lot of space empty. To illustrate my issue, here is a picture of opening the dialog (on an unusually high resolution to demonstrate the issue better):

[image]

The higher the resolution, the greater this space.

Here is a code snippet:

```
<RelativeLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools">

    <!--This is the yellow box-->
    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/dialog_button_bar"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        style="?android:buttonBarStyle"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">
        [Buttons...]
    </LinearLayout>

    <!--This is the red box-->
    <ScrollView
        android:layout_above="@id/dialog_button_bar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">
        [LinearLayout containing rows...]
    </ScrollView>
```

If I remove the `android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"` and the `android:layout_above="@id/dialog_button_bar"` attributes, the whole layout jumps to the top and now the empty space is below my layout.

What am I doing wrong? :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems like this is some kind of intended behavior. The standard Android app installation dialog seems to behave the same way (leaving a lot of blank space between the permission part and the buttons) so I guess I'll keep it this way...

Answer (score 0):

Create new Style in styles.xml

```
<style name="MyCustomDialog" parent="Base.Theme.AppCompat.Light.Dialog">
    <item name="android:windowNoTitle">true</item>
    <item name="windowActionBar">false</item>
</style>
```

Now in AndroidManifest.xml, add android:theme="@style/MyCustomDialog" to your Dialog activity.

Comment: did not help :(